# Redux: Object destructuring in connect function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a state that I want to map to my component: `cache`.

```
    const component = connect(state => ({ ...searchState(state), ...cache(state) }), 
    mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

However, cache contains a lot of necessary properties I dont want.

I only want to map `foo` to my App.

I've tried the following but `foo` doesn't appear to get mapped.

```
    const component = connect(state => ({ ...searchState(state), ...cache(state).foo }), 
    mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Is there some handy ES6 or ES7 magic I can use to strip out that single property and omit the rest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip the spread, and assign to a property:

```
const component = connect(state => ({ ...searchState(state), foo: cache(state).foo }), 
mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```